# Hive redirect output to file with \N for NULL value

Tags: redirect, null, hive

I am runig a hive query and redirecting its output to a file

```
$ hive -e "select id, age from employee" > /tmp/1
$ cat /tmp/1
1 44
2 32
3 NULL
```

I want the `Null` to be printed as `\N` so that I can upload it to mysql.
This is a sample query but I have more than 20 columns in real and any column can have null value. Writing a if() or case() in select column wont be helpful. I want a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simple case statement should do.

```
$ hive -e "select id
           , case when age is null then '\\\N' else age end as age from employee" > /tmp/1

$ less /tmp/1

id   age
1    44
2    32
3    \N
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have >10  select columns so I want a generic solution that works without changing the select query.

Comment: Don't you think that information would've been helpful to include in your question?